# My loading.gif does not display on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to create a loading screen whenever my button clicks, it executes the Ajax and everything but not the loading screen.

CSS

```
<style>
#display_loading{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
</style>
```

jQuery

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(){
  //$('#loading').show();
  $("#display_loading").html('<img src="C:\Users\jmdsantos\Loading_icon.gif" height="100px" width="100px">')
```

And Below is for closing of the loading GIF through Ajax.

```
$("#display_loading").html('')
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please show the HTML of `#display_loading`.

Comment: what error are you getting?  I am guessing it has got to do with the image path, can you try a path relative to your project like this : "./Loading.icon.gif"

Comment: Oh god sorry for this, i forgot to put my DIV id in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image tag is wrong. It should not put in like that.

It better to hide the image by id or any class using css and then display it on click function.

```js
$("#submit-btn").click(function(){

    $("#display_loading").show();

 });
```

```css
    #display_loading{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
        display:none;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display_loading"><img src="/path to/jmdsantos/Loading_icon.gif" height="100px" width="100px"></div>

<button id="submit-btn">to click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your image path it not should be E&C both drive

E:C:\Users\jmdsantos\Loading_icon.gif

Use only Loading_icon.gif if you are in jmdsantos folder.

Comment: That was a typo i edited :) thanks for the input though!